# How do I continue to add items to array and print

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, arraylist, casting

Tried to simplify my program I am trying to create this tester to test my add and remove methods for my other class and print the list of properties in the array list I am stuck on how to proceed

Please Help

```
public class Tester
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
    }

    public Tester ()
    {
        Apartment testingApartment = new Apartment();
        Basement testingBasement = new Basement();
        Company testingCompany = new Company();// Contains list of
                                                // properties to sell
                                                // in arraylist

        // elements with a 2 after the name are used for the Basement
        // elements

        String Apartmentneighbourhood = "Parkdale";
        String Basementneighbourhood = "Rexdale";
        double price = 400000.99;
        double price2 = 5000000.99;
        int numberofbaths = 3;
        int numberofbaths2 = 5;
        int numberofbedrooms = 2;
        int numberofbedrooms2 = 4;
        int squarefoot = 3000;
        int squarefoot2 = 5000;
        int floors = 4;
        int floorlevel = 4;

        testingApartment.setneighbourhood(apartmentneighbourhood);
        testingBasement.setneighbourhood(Basementneighbourhood);
        testingApartment.setprice(price);
        testingBasement.setprice(price2);
        testingApartment.setbathNum(numberofbaths);
        testingBasement.setbathNum(numberofbaths2);
        testingApartment.setbedNum(numberofbedrooms);
        testingBasement.setbedNum(numberofbedrooms2);
        testingApartment.setsqrft(squarefoot);
        testingBasement.setsqrft(squarefoot2);
        testingApartment.setNumFloors(floors);
        testingBasement.setFloorLevel(floorlevel);
    }
}
```

Here is my add method from my Apartment Class

```
public void addApartment(Apartment newApartment)
    {
      Apartment ApartmentInput = new Apartment();
        ApartmentInput = newApartment;
    Arraylist.add(ApartmentInput);
    }
```

Comment: I think your code doesn't even compile yet, I was looking at the main method, it doesn't look completed yet, could you edit that?

Comment: Much better, thank you, give me a few minutes, I'll have something up for ya, I'm a bit busy right now

Comment: Can you post a compilable code?

Comment: I am trying to fix code I'm not sure as to why the code is not compiling I'm working on trying to fix it and I'll post it as soon as I find the issue.

Comment: Well nevermind then, I think they got you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list of appartments has the name Arraylist (which is not advisable) then

```
for(Apartment apartment in Arraylist) {
    System.out.println(apartment.toString());
}
```

Would be a start. You could implement a toString method on the apartment class to make that work.

Another warning - the method

```
public void addApartment(Apartment newApartment)
{
    Apartment ApartmentInput = new Apartment();
    ApartmentInput = newApartment;
    Arraylist.add(ApartmentInput);
}
```

Has some issues. You're not following normal Java naming conventions. Variables should begin with a lowercase letter. The `new Apartment()` code block is irrelevant since you immediately reassign `ApartmentInput` with the value from the input parameter `newApartment`. Similarly, the `ApartmentInput` local variable is redundant as you already have the value in `newApartment`.

Hope this is useful.

I have assumed that Arraylist is the name of an instance of the ArrayList class if not, then put

```
ArrayList<Apartment> apartmentList = new ArrayList<>();
```

somewhere in the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

Your `addApartment` method needs to be in your `Company` class (the class you said will hold the list of properties of apartments, and the class that holds the `ArrayList`). If you want to run your code that you commented out, then your `addApartment` method needs to change its arguments from an `Apartment` to the arguments you specify that "make up" this apartment.

```
testingCompany.addApartment(Apartmentneighbourhood, price, numberofbaths, numberofbedrooms, squarefoot, floornumbers);
```

OR you need to change your commented out code to be

```
Apartment newApartment = new Apartment(Apartmentneighbourhood, price, numberofbaths, numberofbedrooms, squarefoot, floornumbers);
testingCompany.addApartment(newApartment);
```

Finally, your need to change your `addApartment` method to take in the correct variables, and/or make it use the input `Apartment` instead of creating a new one.

```
public void addApartment(Apartment newApartment) {
    instanceOfArrayList.add(newApartment);
}
```

OR

```
public void addApartment(String nbhd, double price, int baths, int beds, int squareFt, int floors) {
    Apartment toAdd = new Apartment(nbhd, price, baths, beds, squareFt, floors);
    instanceOfArrayList.add(toAdd);
}
```

Note that in both methods, you add the Apartments to an *instance of* an array list in your `Company` class.  This `ArrayList` needs to be initialized in the constructor of your class so that you can call the add method of it whenever you want to. The method add is not a static method, so calling `ArrayList.add()` should not work (unless I'm mistaken). So keep track of your added Apartments in your instance of an array list. The class should have the global variable `ArrayList<Apartment> instanceOfArrayList;`, and the constructor should initialize it:

```
instanceOfArrayList = new ArrayList<Apartment>();
```

Finally, to print all the information about the apartments, you can just loop over all elements in your ArrayList (`instanceOfArrayList.size()`), and print out the information of each `Apartment` in a nice way of your choice.